# unable to see android project downloaded from java.2s

Tags: android

The following image is shown when i open project downloaded [from here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android_Free_Code/Game_libgdx/Download_Free_code_PestalotiopsisMicrospora.htm)

[image]
Help me fix the issue.The project is done in libgdx.

Do I need to download any software?

Answer (score 0):

Its not a gradle project, try to import.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import eclipse project if this not help you u can just copy-paste and build gradle project.